# Why are REIT stocks tanking and defaulting?

Tags: reit

I have some REIT stocks in my IRA.  One of them just announced 2 weeks ago a normal dividend while their price was stable.  Within that time, it dropped 75%, then they announced they "can't cover their margins", their stock is now worth pennies.  How does that happen?  Why does it appear fine and 9 trading days later it's worthless.  There seems to be something about the REIT industry I'm missing as it's happening all over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any ideas why REITS seem to be headed to zero?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121978/any-ideas-why-reits-seem-to-be-headed-to-zero)

Comment: I wish I saw that yesterday!

Comment: Was the fund previously making yearly dividend payments totaling around 10%? That level of return is indicative of a fairly high level of risk considering the risk-free rate of return was somewhere around 2%. It's clearly higher than the overall stock market since the overall stock market doesn't return 10%.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 2% is a horrible return.  If the markets average return is 7%, taking into consideration that an REIT does not pay taxes and the income the stockholder makes is taxed as income tax, it makes sense that it would have a higher return than the market, and great for retirement accounts that are not taxed.

Comment: @rtaft You are very, very wrong. 2% is a great return if you can't accept any risk. With treasuries going negative, many investors would gladly take a 2% risk-free return. You can't even find that these days. So 10% would necessarily mean quite a bit of risk. (If you disagree, please tell me where I can find a 2% risk-free return.)